# Laravel Eloquent: Relationships multiple have issue & Eloquent “select” method not working with using “with” method

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I am try to made Eloquent: Relationships for three model. Please have a look on my code.

```
    $account = Account::select(['id', 'is_sign_contract', 'restaurant_name', 'state', 'phone_no', 'email', 'one_time_pick_up', 'sign_contract_date', 'created_at', 'oil_on_hand', 'binsize'])
            ->with(['completedservice' => function($c) {
               //$c->select('id');
                }])
            ->with(['accountService' => function($q) {
                    $q->with(['serviceProvider' => function($qs) {
                        $qs->select('id', 'company_name');
                    }])->select('account_id', 'service_provider_id', 'service_id');
                }])
                    ->whereRaw($where)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->offset(54)->limit(1)->get();
```

if i remove that //$c->select('id'); select form above relation then i get data if i am using it display blank relationship block.

below image for response in last image whole function there

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

In short without select it works fine, but if I am using select then not working.

Comment: Is it `addSelect` as in the pic or `//$c->select('id');` as in code ? and is completedservice model has an ID field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel loads the relations after the first query is run. In order for it to attach the related model to the parent you need to select the foreign key on the related table so Laravel knows which model to attach the child to after the query is run.

The `accountService` works because ytou are selecting `account_id` on that model to attach it to `Account` and `serviceProvider` works because you are selecting `id` on `serviceProvider` as well as `service_provider_id` on `accountService` so after all queries are run Laravel knows which models get attached where.

Your query is not working because you are not selecting the `account_id` on the child model.

The following will work:

```
$account = Account::select(['id', 'is_sign_contract', 'restaurant_name', 'state', 'phone_no', 'email', 'one_time_pick_up', 'sign_contract_date', 'created_at', 'oil_on_hand', 'binsize'])
    ->with(['completedservice' => function($c) {
        $c->select('id', 'account_id');
    }])
    ->with(['accountService' => function($q) {
        $q->with(['serviceProvider' => function($qs) { 
            $qs->select('id', 'company_name');
        }])
        ->select('account_id', 'service_provider_id', 'service_id');
    }])
    ->whereRaw($where)
    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->offset(54)->limit(1)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Tucker for helping me. i am just frustrated with this issue. thank you so much help me out. that time i don't know what happens with me. i am not try to think wisely on it. Thanks again for your valuable reply.

Comment: Don't worry about it, that's what SO is for. I only know the answer to this question because I had spent hours debugging it in the past ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the foreign key selected along with any other fields you wish to select. Without which you'll get an empty relationship. So it should be something similar to `$c->select('id', 'account_id');`

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my query. i will appreciate. but i think  @eric already mention that above answer. and he write it in English as you.. so i understand what he said.